# Minimize Skype window to system tray

Tags: linux, skype, kubuntu

I am using Skype 5.4.0.1 for Linux Beta on Kubuntu 14.4. Until recently I was able to press the "close" button and Skype would be minimized to the system tray (little icon). Meaning it would not be in the task bar as a minimized window. How can I do this in the new version?

Comment: If there isn't an option to enable this feature then it cannot be done in the new version.  You can always roll back to the previous version, at least until, that version can no longer be used to connected to the Skype network.

Comment: One can use `wmctrl -c Skype` to minimise *Skype* automatically, after it booted up. So, just edit the startup script to call `wmctrl` as well.

Comment: See [How do I start skype in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161577/113421) question at AskUbuntu, which has an answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround that'll be sufficient for most users.
I'll describe it for Xfce, but it'll also work with other desktop environments.

Right-click the application's window, and select "Move to Another Workspace" -> "2 (Workspace 2)".

The Skype icon will remain in the notification area, but its window button (and window) will not.
Skype's notifications about incoming chats and such will still show up.

If necessary, you can switch workspaces with Ctrl+Alt+arrow-left/right.